# Can a website know that a request is coming through the "requests" python library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been trying to get the coordinates for CVS stores. When I type a URL that should go to a New Jersey location it always redirects me to the center of Philadelphia.  I tried deleting my cookies thinking that could make a difference but it did not.

Here is script:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import json 
import csv 
from requests.exceptions import InvalidURL, MissingSchema 
import re

urlx = "http://www.cvs.com/store-locator/cvs-pharmacy-address/557+South+Atlantic+Avenue-Aberdeen-NJ-07747/storeid=2511" 
rx = requests.get(urlx) 
soupx = BeautifulSoup(rx.content)
lat = soupx.find(attrs={'id':'toLatitude'})['value'] 
long = soupx.find(attrs={'id':'toLongitude'})['value'] 
print lat, long
```

There are unused libraries because this is essentially a snippet of a larger script, however this is the part of the script that is not functioning properly.  The requests.get(urlx) function does not seem to pull from the Aberdeen, NJ url but instead some site in Philadelphia, any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Following the link brought me to a store in Chicago, but subsequent visits to the Aberdeen, NJ store. It is possible you have to set a store when first visiting and then visits after will be to the correct store.

Comment: Are you close to Chicago? I'm very close to Philadelphia so maybe it has something to do with the IP.  I wouldn't know how to "set a store" programmatically.  I am essentially running this script for every store in New Jersey and they all come back as Philadelphia.

Comment: Not entirely, closer to Kansas City.  It looks like it calls this javascript function: `setMyCvsStore(storeId)` which basically does an ajax call to `http://cvs.com/rest/bean/cvs/store/CvsStoreLocatorServices/getAddStoreToFavoriteList` with `"data":{"storeId":"storeId"}`. It also appears to set a cookie `favorite_store` with a value of the store information. For the Chicago store: `4793/41.86681/-87.65684/CHICAGO/IL`.

Comment: Changing this cookie appears to change the favorite store, so you could just set a cookie possibly and then pass it in with all of your requests.

Comment: OK that kind of makes sense to me.  Would the favorite_store cookie information have to change for every new store URL that gets passed in or could it stay the same? Because right now when I iterate through all 300+ NJ URL's they all end up as Philadelphia, not just the first site which is the above Aberdeen URL.

Comment: It should be able to stay the same. It is possible they have something else they are checking, because adding the cookie doesn't appear to make a difference. You will also need to add a valid `user-agent` as they may "block" ones that don't look like normal `user-agents`. Because I changed it to my current browsers user agent and it worked properly.

Comment: I added a line for User Agents and it still has the wrong coordinates.  I am not sure how to set up the favorite store cookie. Below is the line I added for User-Agents `UA = {'User-Agent': <Valid User Agent>}` and then added this to the request line `rx = requests.get(urlx, headers= UA)`   User agents is new to me in Python so maybe something is wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at my updated code within my answer. It should work properly now, at least it did on my machine after leaving the interpreter multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the first time you enter the link it will set your favorite store to one that is near you. And all subsequent requests will go to the actual store in question because a `favorite_store` cookie has been saved. You can emulate this by adding a [cookie](http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) to your request. This is not enough as they appear to be blocking "abnormal" `user-agent` values, so you will need to set a proper [user-agent](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

**Edit:** after some testing it appears just setting the `cookies={'favorite_store':'store'}` doesn't work correctly so I would send the first request and then grab the cookies from it as it should have the `favorite_store` set. I have updated code below for this change.

You should be able to set the `favorite_store`, and `user-agent` like so:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from requests.exceptions import InvalidURL, MissingSchema 
import re

urlx = "http://www.cvs.com/store-locator/cvs-pharmacy-address/557+South+Atlantic+Avenue-Aberdeen-NJ-07747/storeid=2511"
cookies = requests.get(urlx).cookies
rx = requests.get(urlx, cookies=cookies, headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})

soupx = BeautifulSoup(rx.content)
lat = soupx.find(attrs={'id':'toLatitude'})['value'] 
long = soupx.find(attrs={'id':'toLongitude'})['value'] 
street_address = ", ".join([soupx.find(attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'}).text,soupx.find(attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'}).text, soupx.find(attrs={'itemprop':'addressRegion'}).text ])
print lat, long, street_address
```

Comment: That last change to the cookies did it. You are a god. Thank you so much.